# Instrumenting java core libraries

Tags: java

When we compile a java program, we get .class files. Can I access these .class files of java core libraries? e.g. can I have access to java.lang.String.class ?

Actually I am doing a research and trying to find branch coverage of some java core libraries. The tool I am using for branch coverage actually instruments the .class files.

Thanks

Comment: instead of bytecode instrumentation, couldn't you also directly take the source code for the entire JRE from the OpenJDK 7 and have the AST for every .java file (including String.java) and do source code instrumentation directly there?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you said but my scenario is like I am using a tool for automated testing and a separate tool for branch coverage. I wanted to use both of them as it is as otherwise tweaking the tools would take too much time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in `rt.jar` in your JRE directory. You've even got the sources in `src.zip`. (Or you could just pull the latest version of [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/).)

Also, if you want to instrument the base classes, you'll also need to specify a boot classpath. Look at the `-Xbootclasspath` option for `java`: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: Aren't there any security issues? Doesn't the security manager check that the Java runtime classes are intact?

Comment: @Pèter, it's been a while since I tried this, but I don't recall it doing so.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, it's right there, in `jre/lib/rt.jar` inside your `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: so basically I unJar it, instrument the classes and then jar it again and place it in the same directory. correct?

Comment: In order not to break your install, I'd advise you to use the `-Xbootclasspath` instead.

Comment: Yeah, that should work for research. Don't do it in any serious production, though.

Comment: I understand this is an old post, i want know how do you instrument the classes after exploding the rt.jar ? is it the pom.xml plugin instrument goal that will automatically instrument all the classes ? if so, where should be the classes be exploded into for jacoco to pick them up and instrument the classes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the class files are inside the #{JDK INSTALL PATH}/jre/lib/rt.jar archive. Or if you use an IDE like Eclipse you can ctrl+click on any string method, or on "String" in declarations like `private String var;` to open that class.